# CRON - CURL on Godady Server says 404 page not found

Tags: php, curl

Though the page exists at http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php

When i run the following command it says

*/2 *   *   *   *   curl --silent --compressed "http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php"

Am i missing some PHP execution here?

**Email file just sends an email which works great and i get the email**

**Error i am getting is**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /stockcode/email.php was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net Port 80</address>
</body></html>


* About to connect() to ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /stockcode/email.php HTTP/1.1

> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2

> Host: ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net

> Accept: */*

>

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

< Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 17:06:01 GMT

< Server: Apache

< Content-Length: 303

< Connection: close

< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<

{ [data not shown]

101   303  101   303    0     0   250k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  295k* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: looks like your trying to run a shell command from within php? did you wrap it in `exec` or `shell_exec`? in any case you'd be better to use php's curl https://php.net/curl

Comment: run this same command from the command-line, add the -v option to curl in order to see output verbosely.

Comment: @andrew I am calling it from Cron, command line so shall i change something in the command ?

Comment: @Smokie will it look like */2 * * * * curl --v --compressed "http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php" ?

Comment: @user580950 Run this command from your cron `curl -i -v "http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php" > /var/tmp/somefile.txt` and update yoru question with the content of the txt file(removing the htmls). Also change the file path.

Comment: @user580950 nvrmind, I thought you were calling it from php as you tagged php

Comment: @user580950, i just ran the curl command from my machine pointing to that url and it returned 200 which is ok. could you post your output from the curl command using -v switch ?

Comment: yes i am trying to post the log now using curl -i -v "http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php" > /var/tmp/somefile.txt

Comment: * About to connect() to ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /stockcode/email.php HTTP/1.1

> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2

> Host: ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net

> Accept: */*

Comment: Here is the output http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/somfile.txt

Comment: did you mean http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/somefile.txt :) ?

Comment: yes thats right sorry about that

Comment: please include the curl messages as well.. About to connect() to ip-50-62-165-2 ...

Comment: @Smokie yes updated the post with messages

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, but try to change the user-agent:
curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" "http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php"

Comment: @Smokie and how do i do that in curl ?

Comment: curl -v --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" http://ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php

Comment: is the address ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/stockcode/email.php accessable from your browser?

Comment: @smokie yes is is accessible from browser

Comment: using the same machine you're executing the cron job from ?

Comment: @Smokie no from different machine

Answer (score 1):

Note the line 'Trying 127.0.0.1... connected'. 
curl is connecting to your own machine rather than the host you specified. please check the hosts file (in your machine that is executing the cron job!) and see if you have a line similar to:

```
127.0.0.1 ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net
```

comment it out or remove it and try again.

the hosts file is located in /etc/hosts in *nix machines, or in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\ in windows ones.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the CRON command on Godaddy Server to 
**/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-165-226.ip.secureserver.net/httpdocs/stockcode/email.php**